# Gtk event handling

Tags: gtk

I need to only handle mouse up and mouse down on images to replace those images with other images.

I am using eventbox right now but it seems like it might be overkill. Is there a lightweight alternative?

I imagine I could wrap the entire widget collection I'm using(sorta like a toolbar) and then do my own hit testing. Is there an easier way? Does gtk have some helper routines built in?

Obviously the hit testing is not difficult but just curious, as it's still a bit of extra plumbing that I might not need to re-implement? Or maybe eventbox is pretty lightweight?

Comment: event box is lightweight in most scenarios. go with it.

Comment: @JoséFonte Well, I have to double up every object I want to interact which is most ;/ So, at the very least it nearly doubles the xml code, not entirely light weight ;)

Comment: GtkImage does not have a GdkWindow so you should use the event box if you want to receive events. Quote from the API: **GtkImage is a “no window” widget (has no GdkWindow of its own), so by default does not receive events. If you want to receive events on the image, such as button clicks, place the image inside a GtkEventBox, then connect to the event signals on the event box.**. The widget itself is "light" as it's basically a container and doesn't draw anything. If a big xml file to hold the GtkBuilder file has a high cost on your solution,do it programatically.

Comment: @JoséFonte You are missing the point. I obviously read that or I'd be asking a different question. You are say they are light but you expect me to trust your opinion when I do not know you or your experience with the exact topic under question. You have stated no facts.  I am not talking about eventbox's drawing footprint but it's overhead for managing event handling. I only need to handle one event for my image, a button click, yet eventbox will try and add all kinds of events that are not necessary. This introduces unnecessary overhead... overhead that may add up.

Comment: You can claim that it is insignificant relative to the entire program, but that is irrelevant. I don't believe in creating unnecessary waste. It is an effort of implementation vs overhead issue and you haven't presented any facts that would allow me to make an informed and intelligent decision. Obviously eventbox is not going to be extremely heavy, but that doesn't mean it's extremely light. It still has to do work. If I end up with 10000 eventbox'es and take your advice, I bet my program will suffer when simple hit testing wouldn't.

Comment: Well. It seems you already know the answer. Good luck

Comment: @JoséFonte I don't know the answer, which is why I asked the question. But it seems you need to work on your ego a little. I asked a question and expect a factual answer and not your opinion that you want me to except so you can feel superior and fill your egotistical need. "event box is lightweight in most scenarios. go with it." Is not factual. You simply want me to do what you say. Thanks for *not* helping and then trying to justify it and make it like it was my fault.

Comment: @JoséFonte Thanks, I appreciate it! I know you mean well. Maybe one day I can repay you for all the help you've given me! Peace!

Comment: Check GtkWidget add_events/ser_events functions or methods, depending on your language of choice. Peace. Good luck